# How to add list box in action script 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, listbox

I want to add simple list/combo box with action script 3 . but i have not found anything in internet.

Can anyone give me sough rough idea with some dummy values

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add combobox from Window-combobox delete from stage  then add the following code

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;

var combo:ComboBox = new ComboBox();

addChild(combo);


combo.move(50,50);

combo.addItem( { label: "Item 1"  } );

combo.addItem( { label: "Item 2"  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flash then use the components "combobox" for the simplest dropdown/checkbox. see here for basic skinning etc: [skinning-the-combobox-flash-component](http://www.zedia.net/2010/skinning-the-combobox-flash-component/).

if not then there are plenty of things out there on google that will fit your need, eg: [opensource dropdown](http://www.christeso.com/blog/index.php/lab/as3-drop-down-menu-class/)